# Variable in AWS IAM role to grant permissions to Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to design an AWS IAM role that would dynamically grant permission to resource based on the name of the calling resource. For example I currently have a role that grants a Lambda function permission to create and write CloudWatch logs, which looks like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "CWLog",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/MyLambdaFunction*"
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to substitute the string **MyLambdaFunction** for the name of the calling Lambda function using some **${aws:NameOfTheLambdaFunction}** variable, so that I can have a generic policy allowing functions to write only to their specific CW log groups that I can attach to different Lambda roles - with the resource statement looking like: `"Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/${aws:NameOfTheLambdaFunction}*"`

Is something like this possible?

Comment: To my knowledge, unfortunately, this is not possible. It's a good feature request!

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to an [IAM policy variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) which provides you the name of the calling Lambda function.

Unfortunately, this policy variable **does not currently exist** and so this isn't possible.